# Voice memo does not use the digital output socket

Tags: iphone

iPhone 4 voice memos will not play on my docking station. Is this normal or do I have a problem? The iPod app plays fine, and of course I can connect to the headphone jack, but what about the dock socket?

Comment: I say you have a problem. And we may need more info. I've got no idea about the dock, but usually it's good to know which dock it is and what's your iOS version.

Comment: Dock is Bose SoundDock. IOS is iPhone 4 latest version. I was assuming that maybe apps need to specifically enable sound output through the dock socket and that Voice Memo doesn't